# C++/JAVA: Efficiently find a set in the collection containing given value

Tags: java, c++, optimization, set

Suppose that we have a collection of mutually exclusive sets 
    {A,B,C,D} where **A** = {1,2,3}, **B** = {4,5,6}, **C** = {7,8,9}, **D** = {10,11,12}

And given a value **Z**, for example of 3, I expect it to return the index of set A, because A has 3 as its member.

**The question is that how could I do it efficiently using C++ or JAVA.**

**My current solution:** Store the A,B,C,D as a HashSet (or unordered_set in C++) in the container and loop through each set until a set containing **Z** is found.
    The problem is that the complexity is O(n) for the amount of sets stored in the container.

**Is there any way (or any data structure to store those sets) to do that faster than O(n)?**

Comment: TBH if your sets are this simple, just use an array of `char`, it takes less memory and very fast access.

Comment: @Olayinka: It's exactly the other way round. If his sets are really so small, then there will probably be no significant difference between O(n) and O(1), so why introduce all the dangers and problems associated with arrays, rather than choosing the robust and semantically correct solution? And as far as C++ is concerned, why arrays and not `std::vector` (or `std::array` if the size is known at compile-time)?

Comment: @TruthseekerRangwan: How much can you change about the general structure of your code? Where does your input come from? Are you stuck with receiving a collection of sets? Can you assume anything else about the set contents (e.g. is the smallest value in B guaranteed to be greater than the greatest in A, or is there an ordering relationship between the sets)? I have the feeling that your question is too much centered around micro-optimisation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a map that maps a value to set id(for example it should map 1, 2, 3 to A, 4, 5 and 6 to B and so on). With a hash map, it can work in O(1) on average.

Comment: @TruthseekerRangwan you don't map the set as key, you make each element of the set as key 1 -> A, 2 -> A, 12 -> D

Comment: Assuming that the OP's input mechanism cannot be modified, this solution just moves the problem to another place. Finding the set ID at the end will be fast, but this comes at the cost of creating the map before that.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick heuristic that can help try to bubble most actively used sets up in the list. It is likely that most of the time there would be one or two sets that are returned on 80-90% of requests.

```
int getSetIndex(Object elem) {
    Set first = sets.get(0);
    if (first.contains(elem))
        // if "index of the set" has some special meaning in your question,
        // you should save it along with the set
        return first.index();
    for (int i = 1; i < sets.size(); i++) {
        Set cur = sets.get(i);
        if (cur.contains(elem)) {
            sets.set(i, sets.get(i - 1));
            sets.set(i - 1, cur);
            return cur.index();
        }
    }
    return -1; // not found
}
```